# Javascript if statement using :checked and .bind but only one option works

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, radio-button

I am trying to create an Override Button to disable auto-complete for a form I am building and would like to use Javascript to have div "manualOverrideWarning" to display a warning if the button is selected. The problem is that the function only works the first time the user presses the button but then does not remove the warning once the override is turned off. Any and all pointers in how I used Javascript wrong in my code would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Html:

```
    Manual Overide: 
            <label>No <input type="radio" 
name="manualOverride" id="manualOverrideNo" value="no" checked /></label>
            <label>Yes<input type="radio" 
name="manualOverride" id="manualOverrideYes" value="yes" /></label>

            <div id="manualOverrideWarning">test</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#manualOverrideYes, #manualOverrideNo').bind('change', function () {
    if($('input[name="manualOverrideYes"]:checked')) {
        $('#manualOverrideWarning').text('Autocomplete Disabled!');
    } else {
    if($$('#manualOverrideWarning').text(''));
    }
});
```

Thanks again y'all! You all are my heroes!

Answer (score 2):

I would do your check with [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if($('input[name="manualOverrideYes"]').is(':checked')) {
```

Or if you like your original version then you would need to check the `length` property to see if any results were actually returned:

```
if($('input[name="manualOverrideYes"]:checked').length)
```

---

Also it looks like you have a typo here:

```
if($$('#manualOverrideWarning').text(''));
```

I assume that should be

```
if($('#manualOverrideWarning').text(''));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. I tried what you said but now when I click 'Yes' it only outputs the 'No' text and doesn't change when I click 'Yes' again. So it looks like the check is still saying that the 'manualOverrideYes' button is not checked regardless of what I choose. Any ideas?

Comment: My mistake I forgot to point out that I had saw that and fixed that already. The same problem continues. But thank you for trying!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to test the selected element against a selector

```
if($('input[name="manualOverrideYes"]').is(':checked')) {
```

`$('input[name="manualOverrideYes"]:checked')` returns a jQuery wrapper object which will always be truthy.

If the checkbox is selected then the jQuery wrapper will contain 1 element else 0 element, but still a object will be returned.

Another way to use it is to test the length of the returned object like

```
if($('input[name="manualOverrideYes"]:checked').length) {
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. I tried what you said but now when I click 'Yes' it only outputs the 'No' text and doesn't change when I click 'Yes' again. So it looks like the check is still saying that the 'manualOverrideYes' button is not checked regardless of what I choose. Any ideas?